# Intersecting Mongoid "in"-Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

According to the [mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html) on Explicit Merging ("Queryable#in - defaults to intersect") I would expect the following query:

```
Contact.in(id: ['a', 'b']).in(id: ['b', 'c'])
```

to result in something like this:

```
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>{"$in"=>["b"]}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Contact
  embedded: false>
```

But instead I get an overwrite for all imaginable cases:

```
[1] pry(main)> Contact.in(id: ['a', 'b']).in(id: ['b', 'c'])
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>{"$in"=>["b", "c"]}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Contact
  embedded: false>

[2] pry(main)> Contact.in(id: ['a', 'b']).intersect.in(id: ['b', 'c'])
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>{"$in"=>["b", "c"]}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Contact
  embedded: false>

[3] pry(main)> Contact.in(id: ['a', 'b']).union.in(id: ['b', 'c'])
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>{"$in"=>["b", "c"]}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Contact
  embedded: false>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Interesting enough, if I use field name other than `id` — `_id` or any random field name, it works properly. Using `_id` in your case may be a way to go, but it still looks like a bug.

Comment: Actually, it would behave in this strange way not only with `_id` but with field aliases as well. I think I know how to fix that in Origin.

Comment: That's the solution, thanks. It works using ```_id```. Should I open an issue for the Origin project on github? Or since you know how to fix it, do you open a pull-request? Would be great!

Comment: I just opened a PR fixing this — https://github.com/mongoid/origin/pull/83

Comment: @Phil please answer your own question and mark it as resolved if you found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is caused by Mongoid gem. Upgrading to latest version of Mongoid gem will solve the issue.

More information regarding the bug can be found here

https://github.com/mongoid/origin/pull/83